# Umbraco - Safari - TinyMCE removes style

Tags: safari, tinymce, umbraco, html

I have a problem with the tinyMCE editor in the Umbraco backoffice with Safari 5.1.7.
When I create a new node, put some text in bold or italic and I click Save & Publish, it's fine. But when I go back to my node and publish it again, these elements are remove and I only have simple text.

So the saved text isn't well loaded in the editor. Here is what I have before publishing the first time :

```
<p><strong><em>Hello !</em></strong></p>
```

here what is loaded :

```
<p><span class="Apple-style-span"><span class="Apple-style-span">Hello !</span>    </span></p>
```

(the text in the textarea is in bold and italic).

Is there a solution to avoid this problem ?
I don't have this issue with Chrome, Firefox, Opera or IE.

Comment: Hi, could you please let us know which version of Umbraco this is? I can't find a definitive answer on this right now, but I vaguely recall that they recently updated the TinyMCE version used by umbraco which may have already addressed this issue? We had a client also using Safari complain about other related issues with the editor; we suggested she just use Chrome or Firefox instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is a known issue in version 4.5.2 and perhaps 4.6.1.  This CodePlex issue that looks like your problem (http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/28860) doesn't have a fix version.  I would go and vote it up.

There was a Safari TinyMCE issue fixed in version 4.8 so it may be worth trying that version and see if it still exists. (http://umbraco.codeplex.com/workitem/30194)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm using Umbraco 4.7.2 so I'll try someday the 4.8.